# Child component list not rendering

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a list using a child component and it ends up not rendering anything.

Snippet in PropertyBar component:

```
updateSelectedCell() {
    if (graph.selectedCell != null) {
      this.setState({
        selectedCell: graph.selectedCell,
        cellProperties: Array.from(graph.selectedCell.value.attributes)
      });
    }
  }

  renderPropertyList() {
    this.state.cellProperties.map(key => {
      <PropertyBarItem name={key.nodeName} value={key.nodeValue} />
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.selectedCell != null) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" fullWidth={true} onClick={() => this.updateSelectedCell()}> View properties </Button>
          <List>
            {this.renderPropertyList}
          </List>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" fullWidth={true} onClick={() => this.updateSelectedCell()}> View properties </Button>
        <List>
          <p>Click on a cell to view its properties.</p>
        </List>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

When a user clicks on the button, it updates the state with an array then should render a list of PropertyBarItem with the keys inside the array. It ends up not displaying anything, but doesn't crash. Testing using a simple p tag and it also does not render anything:

```
renderPropertyList() {
    this.state.cellProperties.map(key => {
      <p> {key} </p>
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not invoking the `renderPropertyList` method. Add `()` to invoke it.

```
<div>
  <Button
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    fullWidth={true}
    onClick={() => this.updateSelectedCell()}
  >
    View properties
  </Button>
  <List>{this.renderPropertyList()}</List>
</div>
```

You must also return the result from `renderPropertyList` and return the JSX from the function given to `map` as well.

```
renderPropertyList() {
  return this.state.cellProperties.map(key => {
    return <PropertyBarItem name={key.nodeName} value={key.nodeValue} />
  })
}
```

Comment: Woops, I think I had that fixed prior, but a bunch of ctrl-z's might have took me back further than I wanted. But now that I have that fixed, it still doesn't render a list. Even when I put a p tag like `<p> {key} </p>` instead of my child component, nothing gets displayed on the screen.

Comment: @Pierre Have you logged `graph.selectedCell` in `updateSelectedCell` to see that it's not `null`?

Comment: Yup it isn't null. When I click the button to execute `updateSelectedCell`, it renders the portion within the if statement because the `<p>Click on a cell to view its properties.</p>` portion is gone afterwards. So it is rendering the new return statement, just doesn't render the list within `renderPropertyList`.

Comment: @Pierre Great. Is the `this.state.cellProperties` array empty? How is your `List` component handling the `children` prop? Also, check my latest edit. I forgot one thing, sorry.

Comment: Thats it! The additional return for the JSX is what was missing. So does the first `return` within `renderPropertyList` return an array of JSX elements that is created with the second `return` statement?

Comment: @Pierre Great! The first `return` returns the array that is the result of the `map`. Before the `return` inside the function given to `map` was added, you only got an array with `undefined` values, since nothing was returned. What you return from the function given to `map` is what each element in the array will be mapped to in the resulting array.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense. Thanks so much.. again. You also helped me with my last problem so I salute you!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `return` statement:

```
renderPropertyList() {
  return this.state.cellProperties.map(key => {
    <PropertyBarItem name={key.nodeName} value={key.nodeValue} />
  })
}
```

Also, be sure to invoke the method:

```
 if (this.state.selectedCell != null) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" fullWidth={true} onClick={() => this.updateSelectedCell()}> View properties </Button>
          <List>
            {this.renderPropertyList()}
          </List>
        </div>
      )
    }
```